# Are Trinidad and Tobago as well as Suriname safe places to travel alone?

Tags: caribbean, suriname, trinidad-and-tobago

I'm planning to travel alone in South America starting from Colombia.

I'm thinking to do a triangle route between Colombia, Trinidad and Tobago and Suriname.

It'll be a backpacking trip hosting in hostel or something. I don't know nobody who lives in these countries and I have no intentions to hire a guide or something else.

The question is: Is safe to cross through these countries alone?

I'm planning to travel in March 2014.

Comment: March 2013? Traveling back in time? ;-)

Comment: Hahaha! I wanted to say March 2014. Edited! :)

Comment: Your question is both too broad and too subjective. You will get more informative answers if you can more narrowly define what you consider to be "safe," and where in those countries you would be— one can *feel* safe in one part of a city and feel unsafe just two blocks away, and a place that is "safe" from getting mugged at gunpoint may be rather "unsafe" from pickpocketers.

Comment: I think that the definition of safety in the OPs question is quite clear to understand, with a bit of good will. Is namely the ability to walk in the streets of the main cities with rucksack and camera, without being object of attacks just because you seem to be a tourist.

Answer (score 6):

Well I don't know about the other countries, but Suriname is quite safe to cross and travel alone. Although I still recommend you to travel with a guide, just because you might get lost. The people there are very friendly and many of them speak English, so you wont have any problem if you've lost your way. Furthermore there are many different cultures, religions and people.

Comment: I second that. But you only run the risk of getting lost if you go up country. If you stay on the coast, a guide is not at all a necessity (though still a convenience).

Comment: Thanks for tip. Do you know if is possible to across the Suriname to Colombia passing through Guyana?